# Opportunity Split Using APEX and Visulforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, opportunity, opportunity-split

Has anybody developed Opportunity Split and Opportunity Overlay functionality using APEX and Visualforce page ?

I have developed but the problem is I'm using wrapper class inside it so it taking more delay to display split amount when I enter split % and vice Versa. And also some times it will give wrong value.

Please share code snippet if anyone has already developed it.